# How to log message events from AmazonMQ to CloudWatch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-mq

I want to inspect the logs of an [AmazonMQ](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/?amazon-mq.sort-by=item.additionalFields.postDateTime&amazon-mq.sort-order=desc) broker containing information about when a message was enqueued and with which parameters.

AWS provides two options to log activities from the AmazonMQ brokers to CloudWatch called general and audit, but none include the log entries for enqueued messages.

The ActiveMQ official documentation specifies an option called [`loggingBrokerPlugin`](https://activemq.apache.org/logging-interceptor), which can be set to log everything, including events when a message gets enqueued and dequeued. Still, AmazonMQ does not support this option in its configuration. I tried to add this option, but AWS sanitizes the configuration file and removes the entry.

Is there a way around this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible. An alternative is to use CloudWatch, where for particular broker and queue/topic duo you can observe a bunch of metrics. Among them you can find EnqueueCount and DequeueCount ([Monitoring Amazon MQ brokers using Amazon CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazon-mq/latest/developer-guide/security-logging-monitoring-cloudwatch.html)). It is less than ideal, but allows some reasoning about messages going through.